# How can I have a specific authentication section in my web.config by application pool?

Tags: c#, iis, web-config, global-asax

I have a website which shares its auth-token with other apps in my domain : app1.mydomain.com, app2.mydomain.com, .. etc

Now, I want to transform my website to *white-label* it : i.e. The URL will be app1.ANOTHER-COMPANY.com. It will not be in same domain.

I have created a new entry for my white-label in my IIS which will target the same physical folder as my current website, with a virtual directory to override my content folder. 
This folder will contain logos and pictures for my white-label.

It works fine except for authentication which is rejected because my white-label is not in my domain.

I tried to create a virtual directory in my IIS to store an authentication.config and used this in my web.config (using configSource) but it doesn’t work with a virtual directory.

I tried to override my web.config in the AppStart of my global.asax, but when I apply my new settings, it physically erases my web.config.

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        AuthenticationSection section = config.GetSection("system.web/authentication") as AuthenticationSection;
        string extendConfigPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigExtends"] ?? "") + "\\extendsConfig.xml";
        if (section != null && section.Mode == AuthenticationMode.Forms && File.Exists(extendConfigPath))
        {
            XDocument configExtends = XDocument.Load(extendConfigPath);
            section.Forms.Domain = configExtends?.Root?.Element("authenticationDomain")?.Value ?? section.Forms.Domain;
            section.Forms.Name = configExtends?.Root?.Element("authenticationName")?.Value ?? section.Forms.Name;
            config.Save();
        }
```

How can I keep my shared cookie and obtain another for my white-label without domain restriction ?

Comment: Why not create a new physical directory and new website pointing to it with web.config with all necessary configuration values?

Comment: If possible, I would like not to have to publish and maintain two websites